# Vuejs nested JSON data from API not displaying

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

When getting json data from API,Im unable to access nested ppts.

My Vue component

```
var profileComponent = {
    data : function() {
        return {
            isError : false,
            loading : true,
            users : null,
            activeUser : '',                
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        axios
        .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(response => (this.users = response.data))
        .catch(error => {console.log(error);this.isError = true})
        .finally(() => {console.log('GET request from users');this.loading = false})
     },
    template : `
    <div class="profile">
        <div v-if="isError">
            <h3>There was an error</h3>
        </div>
        <div v-else-if='isLoading'>
        Loading
        </div>
        <div v-else>   
                <select v-model="activeUser">
                    <option v-for="user in users" v-bind:value="user">{{ user.name }}</option>
                </select>          
        </div>
        <div class="temp">
            <p>{{ activeUser.address.street }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
`}
```

This Doesnt work but when I change `{{ activeUser.address.street }}` to `{{ activeUser.address }}` it starts working.Note the users object from jsonplaceholder website contains street ppt as well.What am I missing?

Comment: activeUser is an empty string by default so you access activeUser.address it is undefined and if you use activeUser.address.street it gives an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

activeUser is an empty string by default so you access activeUser.address it is undefined and if you use `activeUser.address.street` it gives an error
For resolving this issue you can use

```
<p>{{ (activeUser && activeUser.address)? activeUser.address.street : ''}}</p>
```

instead of simple

```
<p>{{ activeUser.address.street }}</p>
```

Comment: Works now thanks.Will mark this as most useful in some time